# I need know how much bytes has been uploaded for update a progress bar android

Tags: android, progress-bar, http-post, android-asynctask

I am developing an app for upload video to a Apache/PHP Server. In this moment I already can upload videos. I need show a progress bar while the file is being uploaded. I have the next code using AsyncTask and HTTP 4.1.1 Libraries for emulate the FORM.

```
class uploadVideo extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.youtouch.cl/videoloader/index.php");           
        try {
            // Add your data
            File input=new File(fileName);              

            MultipartEntity multi=new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);                

            multi.addPart("video", new FileBody(input));                

            httppost.setEntity(multi);

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);               

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            entity.getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String sResponse = reader.readLine();
            return sResponse;

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.v("Uri Galeria", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();                

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v("Uri Galeria", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();                
        }
        return "error";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unsued) {
                //Here I do should update the progress bar
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String sResponse) {
        try {
            if (pd.isShowing())
                pd.dismiss();

            if (sResponse != null) {
                JSONObject JResponse = new JSONObject(sResponse);
                int success = JResponse.getInt("SUCCESS");
                String message = JResponse.getString("MESSAGE");
                if (success == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Video uploaded successfully",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

I need know where I can get how much bytes has been uploaded. File.length is the total size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my answer here, I guess it answers your question:
But update the file path of the image to your to be uploaded video

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572747/progressbar-in-asynctask-is-not-showing-on-upload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19295719/463846)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried extending FileBody? Presumably the POST will either call `getInputStream()` or `writeTo()` in order to actually send the file data to the server. You could extend either of these (including the InputStream returned by `getInputStream()`) and keep track of how much data has been sent.

Comment: I will try with your answer. Greetings!

Comment: It calls FileBody.writeTo() during post.

Answer (score 3):

thank to cyngus's idea I have resolved this issue. I have added the next code for tracking the uploaded bytes:

Listener on upload button:

```
    btnSubir.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //pd = ProgressDialog.show(VideoAndroidActivity.this, "", "Subiendo Video", true, false);

            pd = new ProgressDialog(VideoAndroidActivity.this);
            pd.setMessage("Uploading Video");
            pd.setIndeterminate(false);
            pd.setMax(100);
            pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pd.show();
            //Thread thread=new Thread(new threadUploadVideo());
            //thread.start();
            new UploadVideo().execute();
        }
    });
```

Asynctask for run the upload:

```
class UploadVideo extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,String> {
    private FileBody fb;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.youtouch.cl/videoloader/index.php");   
        int count;
        try {
            // Add your data
            File input=new File(fileName);

            // I created a Filebody Object
            fb=new FileBody(input);
            MultipartEntity multi=new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            multi.addPart("video",fb);          

            httppost.setEntity(multi);              
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            //get the InputStream
            InputStream is=fb.getInputStream();

            //create a buffer
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];//1024

            //this var updates the progress bar
            long total=0;
            while((count=is.read(data))!=-1){
                total+=count;
                publishProgress((int)(total*100/input.length()));
            }
            is.close();             
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            entity.getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String sResponse = reader.readLine();
            return sResponse;

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.v("Uri Galeria", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();                

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v("Uri Galeria", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();                
        }
        return "error";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... unsued) {        
        pd.setProgress(unsued[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String sResponse) {
        try {
            if (pd.isShowing())
                pd.dismiss();

            if (sResponse != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),sResponse,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i("Splash", sResponse);                 
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }


}
```

The  progress bar load  is bit slow (in starting seems be freeze and then load of 1 to 100 very fast), but works.

Sorry, my english is regular :(.

Comment: It wasn't the solution :(, because the video load isn't related with the progress bar process. With this code is excecuted first the video load and then the progress bar, not in parallel.

Comment: how did you actually solve this ?? Please do tag me if you answer :)

Answer (score 1):

What I used to do is to extends org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity and override the writeTo function like below, while bytes output it will pass though writeTo(), so you can count current output bytes:

```
@Override
public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException 
{
    if (outstream == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Output stream may not be null");
    }

    InputStream instream = new ByteArrayInputStream(this.content);

    try {
        byte[] tmp = new byte[512];
        int total = (int) this.content.length;
        int progress = 0;
        int increment = 0;
        int l;
        int percent;

        // read file and write to http output stream
        while ((l = instream.read(tmp)) != -1) {
            // check progress
            progress = progress + l;
            percent = Math.round(((float) progress / (float) total) * 100);

            // if percent exceeds increment update status notification
            // and adjust increment
            if (percent > increment) {
                increment += 10;
                // update percentage here !!
            }

            // write to output stream
            outstream.write(tmp, 0, l);
        }

        // flush output stream
        outstream.flush();
    } finally {
        // close input stream
        instream.close();
    }
}
```